# Taking input for fstream::seekp and fstream::put

Tags: c++, input

How would I go about taking input for seekp and put for use with hex? Something like this?
    Cin>>hex>>mychar;

How about printing the correct value in hex?
Say at 0x16 the byte is FF or 255 unsigned 8bit(decimal?) when I do this

```
fstream mystream;
mystream.seekp(0x16);
long myvar;
myvar=mystream.tellp();
cout<<"Value at offset 0x16: "<<myvar;
```

It prints 22 im assuming since I opened the file in binary mode thats why its printing 22 as the value of FF in binary is like 2222222 etc.

Is there a correct data type for printing the value at a certain offset(I've tried long and char and int but it still yields 22.) or am I printing them wrong? I've searched on google but couldnt find any help in this regard however I did note that opening the file in binary is recommended for editing with hex.

Comment: If you want read that byte then set offset using seekg(0x16) and read it using v=cin.get() method.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? So I set the offset using seekg? seekp is what I've been using is seekg more suited? How would I set it with cin.get()? Like unsigned short myvar=cin.get(); then just enter hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- `ostream::seekp` sets the "put" pointer, i.e. the location at which one writes data, not the position at which one reads data. Use `istream::seekg` to set the "get" pointer
- `ostream::tellp` doesn't perform any I/O. It merely reports the value of the 'put' pointer, it doesn't actually fetch the data stored there. You mean to use `istream::get`.

Your program is printing the decimal number 22, which is equal to the hexadecimal number 0x16.  That is because `seekp` sets the put pointer to 0x16, and `tellp` merely reports the value of the put pointer -- 0x16!

Try this code:

```
fstream mystream;
mystream.seekg(0x16);
int myvar;
myvar=mystream.get();
cout<<"Value at offset 0x16: "<<myvar << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks mate :D heh Im a little oblivious to these kinds of mistakes.